# Function for finding min number over certain threshold in an array doesn't find numbers below 1 if the threshold is Number.MIN_VALUE. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a function for sorting an array into individual arrays in an array, and i've run into a bit of a problem with Number.MIN_VALUE. On first run, the threshold is set as low as possible, to find min number which is then set as the threshold for the next run. However, with the threshold set at Number.MIN_VALUE, the first run returns only lowest positive number, excluding negative numbers and 0.

If I substitute Number.MIN_VALUE with value, for example, -20, everything works fine. There could be a problem if I didn't know the lowest number in the array however.

```js
const findNumberOverThreshold = (arr, threshold) => {
  let number = Number.MAX_VALUE;
  for (item of arr) {
    if (item < number && item > threshold)
      number = item;
  }
  return number;
}

const array = [-10, 0, 1, 5];
const num = findNumberOverThreshold(array, Number.MIN_VALUE);

console.log({
  num
})
```

Expected output of

```
findNumberOverThreshold(array, Number.MIN_VALUE)
```

would be -10, but actual output is 1.

Comment: Have you looked at setting `number` to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: `Number.MIN_VALUE` is not negative. It's the smallest *positive* non-zero number. Try it with the threshold as `-Infinity` or `-Number.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE):

> The Number.MIN_VALUE property represents the smallest positive numeric
>   value representable in JavaScript.

You can use [`Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NEGATIVE_INFINITY#See_also) instead.

```js
const findNumberOverThreshold = (arr, threshold) => {
  let number = Number.MAX_VALUE;

  for (item of arr) {
    if (item < number && item > threshold)
      number = item;
  }
  return number;
}

const array = [-10, 0, 1, 5];
const num = findNumberOverThreshold(array, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);

console.log({
  num
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to documentation, read the **bold** about the **positive** part:

> The **Number.MIN_VALUE** property represents the **smallest positive** numeric value representable in JavaScript.

Then you can guess why your code is not working. So instead, of the smallest positive, you can use [Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_SAFE_INTEGER)

```js
const findNumberOverThreshold = (arr, threshold) =>
{
  let number = Number.MAX_VALUE;

  for (item of arr)
  {
    if (item < number && item >= threshold)
      number = item;
  }

  return number;
}

const array = [-10, 0, 1, 5];
const num = findNumberOverThreshold(array, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER);

console.log({
  num
});
```